# on page refresh stop html input fields reseting

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a form using HTML, I have put php validations, I want that if form shows validation errors then other input fields should not reset,
only Those fields should reset that have caused Validation Errors,
Plz guide me in this Regard,
Thanks
I am usnig Simple `<form>` and `<input>` tags,
Validation Erros are caused on `Submit`

Comment: please post you code you have done so far.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.. please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of that form field like $_POST['filed_name']

Example:

```
<input type='text' name='field_name' value='<?php echo @$_POST['field_name']; ?>' />
```

Comment: I am using my form code In Wordpress Editor, and IN wordprss PHP Coding is not allowed,

Comment: then how did you validate?... Can you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case You coul;d also use jquery validations

Add this line to include jquery in your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#log").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {
    mail: "required",
    password: "required",
   },
   messages: {
    mail: "Please enter a valid Email id.",
    pass: "Please enter the password.",
   },
  });
 });

</script>
```

View the Html code here

```
<form id='log' action='logindb.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table align='center'>
<tr><td>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
$msg= 0;
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
if($msg == 1)
    echo "<b><font color='green'>Registered Succesfully!..</font></b>";
if($msg == 2)
    echo "<b><font color='green'>Logged out</font></b>";
}
?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align='center'>
<tr><td>
Email id
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='mail' id='mail'>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
Password
</td>
<td>
<input type='password' name='pass' id='pass'>
</td></tr>
</table>
<table align='center'>
<tr><td>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
if($msg == 3)
    echo "<b><font color='red'>User name or password is incorrect...</font></b>";
}
?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align='center'>
<tr><td>
<input type='submit'>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You missed including the jQuery validate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript validation function return false if validation fails like:

```
<script>
if(validate())
{
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
function validate(){
   //your code to validate goes here
return true;
}
</script>
```